# ibm db2 - updating index with adding a new column

Tags: sql, db2

My index was created like :

```
db2 "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX <index_name> ON <table_name> (col_name1 ASC) COMPRESS YES ALLOW REVERSE SCANS"


db2 "alter table <table_name> add constraint <constraint_name> PRIMARY KEY (col_name1)"
```

I now need to add a new column and add it to the key as well.
Here is what I do :

```
db2 "ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD COLUMN col_name2 integer not null default 0"
db2 "ALTER TABLE <table_name> DROP PRIMARY KEY" -- removes the primary key and the generated constraint
db2 "DROP  INDEX <index_name>" -- removes the unique index
db2 "CREATE INDEX <index_name> ON <table_name> (col_name1 ASC, col_name2) COMPRESS YES ALLOW REVERSE SCANS" 
db2 "ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD CONSTRAINT <constaint_name> PRIMARY KEY (col_name1,col_name2)"
```

what happens is that -

it creates the correct indexes I think.

```
db2 describe indexes for table <table_name>
```

shows me one index, where rule_tupe is P and number of columns is 2.
But the db2 console fails with an error :

```
SQL0598W  Existing index "index_name" is used as the index for
the primary key or a unique key.  SQLSTATE=01550
```

So why the error? what am I missing?

Comment: That is not an error, it is a warning (hence the W suffix). This is the expected behaviour.  You can ignore this warning.

Comment: Try this.   Drop the index first.  Then alter tables.  Then look at the describe.  You should be supprised to find out the index is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get the error, when you alter your table to drop the constraint.

Instead of:
db2 "ALTER TABLE  DROP PRIMARY KEY"
Use:
db2 "ALTER TABLE  DROP CONSTRAINT "